# how to get string from string list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of string and there are number of string in the list.
Each string in the list start with number.

```
List<String> stringList=new List<String>();

stringList.Add("01Pramod");
stringList.Add("02Prakash");
stringList.Add("03Rakhi");
stringList.Add("04Test");
stringList.Add("04Test1");
stringList.Add("04Test2");
```

I want a Linq query that will return me list of string that starts with 04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = stringList.Where(i => i.StartsWith("04"));
```

Answer (score 9):

```
stringList.Where(s => s.StartsWith("04"))
```

or

```
stringList.Where(s => s.StartsWith("04")).ToList()
```

if you need a list

Answer (score 1):

Here are the possible solution for it:

```
 // Lambda
 stringList.FindAll(o => o.StartsWith("04"));

 // LINQ
 (from i in stringList
  where i.StartsWith("04")
  select i).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will be easy to understand and its in proper format

var ss=from  string g in stringList

where g.Substring(0,2)=="04"

select g;

foreach(string str in ss)
{
Console.WriteLine(str);
}

Comment: -1 cause these answer was already (and better) given by Peyton three hours before.

Comment: @Oliver: It is not fair. +1 because even though this is not as elegant as others but it will also work. Just because he has another opinion is not the reason to downvote him.

Comment: @zerkms: It is not another opinion, it is the same, but using `Substring()` instead of `StartsWith()`. So it is the same answer as Peytons, but using another string function. So instead of posting the same answer a second time he should upvote Peytons answer instead and delete his own one.

Comment: @Oliver: he is new here, he wants to become the part of community ;-)

Comment: @Oliver: btw, even though I was 15 seconds later than Martin Booth my answer was checked, not him :-S

Comment: @zerkms: Thanks for ur support:)@Oliver:wen i saw the question it was unanswered.. i ll improve my speed:P